# Significant runtime differences performing an PHP-Script from Android (WiFi/GPRS)

Tags: java, php, android, http, url

I'm quite sure that I'm overlooking something very fundamentally but I can't understand the following case:

On the one hand i got my Android-app which I may start with using WiFi or GRPS.

On the other hand i got a **PHP-Script** on an independent server which executes a relatively complex algorithm, but **returns just a few bytes (about 80)**.

The **Android-App** connects to the server and triggers the PHP-Script by a normal URLConnection, fetches the InputStream and processes it.

Now, when I do that on WiFi, its quite fast. But if I just use GPRS/EDGE its about 10-20 times slower.

*Thats what i do not understand... I would understand such a difference if the script does return alot of bytes which has to be transferred but these are just a few bytes.*

**I would have thought that the runtime of the PHP-Script on the server is fully independent from whos calling it and is providing the information constantly fast.**

May somebody tell me where these performance differences might arise from?

greetz
rob

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your script isn't running slower-  check your server logs.  What you're seeing is the high latency of cellular data plans.  Basically, it takes a long time for requests to get from your phone to the tower.  It isn't causing your php to run slower, its just taking a while for the data to transfer to your server and back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm sure you are generelly right. But what makes me wonder is the fact that if I reduce the PHP-Scripts complexity - e.g. a simple print_r in the same length, the output of the complex script is - its as fast as WiFi. this - as for me - does refuse the theory that the latency is produced only by the connection time or transferring time. dont you think so?

Comment: maybe i should add that there aren't any input parameters to be transferred

Comment: Like I said-  I'd do some server side logging.  Check when the requests arrived and how long they took to process.  I'd be shocked if they weren't roughly equal.